# Pygame - generating random objects bug

Tags: python, pygame

Good evening, my dear stackoverflowers.
I'm creating a game in Pygame. Until now I wasn't really having any problems, but now I would appreciate some help. I'm trying to create function that will automatically generate new level every time I call it (after defeating every enemy in current level to be more specific). For now I'm generating only images that you don't collide with, only to make levels more nice but I will be using the function for generating objects aswell so it's kinda important for me. So the problem is that I need to continuously update the game window obviously but the function will keep generating everything too as you can see in the video bellow. I have no idea how to make level generate only once and make the game to remember all the images generated (theirs x and y positions) and how to keep them displayed until I call the function again when I come to another level. Any ideas?

**Here is the video:** https://vimeo.com/532903523

**Here is the function and everything you need to know for my problem. It may be harder for you to understand because its not in English but translation would be irritaing so I at least translated the most important things in these two functions.**

```
vytvor_level = create_level
sirka_okna = ´width of the game window´
vyska_okna = ´height of the game window´
trava = grass
kytka = flower
aktulizace_okna = ´updating the game window´
okno = window
hrac.animace_hrace = player.player_animation
hrac.animace_dashe = player.dash_animation
```

```
def vytvor_level():
    for objekt in range(200):
        x = random.randint(0, sirka_okna)
        y = random.randint(0, vyska_okna)
        trava = random.choice(travy)
        okno.blit(trava, (x,y))
        x = random.randint(0, sirka_okna)
        y = random.randint(0, vyska_okna)
        kytka = random.choice(kytky)
        okno.blit(kytka, (x,y))
        
def aktulizace_okna():
    okno.blit(pozadi, (0,0))
    hrac.animace_hrace(okno)
    hrac.animace_dashe(okno)
    vytvor_level()
    py.display.update()
```

**Here is the full code if needed.**

```
import pygame as py
import random
py.init()

sirka_okna = 1000
vyska_okna = 600

okno = py.display.set_mode((sirka_okna, vyska_okna))

py.display.set_caption("Little Hero")

bezi_program = True

# Animace hráče
animaceVpravo = [py.image.load('WR1.png'), py.image.load('WR2.png'), py.image.load('WR3.png'), py.image.load('WR4.png'), py.image.load('WR5.png'), py.image.load('WR6.png')]
animaceVlevo = [py.image.load('WL1.png'), py.image.load('WL2.png'), py.image.load('WL3.png'), py.image.load('WL4.png'), py.image.load('WL5.png'), py.image.load('WL6.png')]
animaceNahoru = [py.image.load('WU1.png'), py.image.load('WU2.png'), py.image.load('WU3.png'), py.image.load('WU4.png'), py.image.load('WU5.png'), py.image.load('WU6.png')]
animaceDolu = [py.image.load('WD1.png'), py.image.load('WD2.png'), py.image.load('WD3.png'), py.image.load('WD4.png'), py.image.load('WD5.png'), py.image.load('WD6.png')]
animaceDash = [py.image.load('DASH1.png'), py.image.load('DASH2.png'), py.image.load('DASH3.png'), py.image.load('DASH4.png'), py.image.load('DASH5.png'), py.image.load('DASH6.png'), py.image.load('DASH7.png')]
animaceStoji = [py.image.load('IDLE1.png'), py.image.load('IDLE2.png'), py.image.load('IDLE3.png'), py.image.load('IDLE4.png'), py.image.load('IDLE5.png'), py.image.load('IDLE6.png')]

# Prostředí
travy = [py.image.load('GRASS1.png'), py.image.load('GRASS2.png'), py.image.load('GRASS3.png'), py.image.load('GRASS4.png'), py.image.load('GRASS5.png'), py.image.load('GRASS6.png')]
kytky = [py.image.load('FLOWERS1.png'), py.image.load('FLOWERS2.png'), py.image.load('FLOWERS3.png'), py.image.load('FLOWERS4.png')]
pozadi = py.image.load('Little_Hero_Pozadi.png')


#------------------------------------------------------

class Hrac:
    def __init__(self, x, y, sirka, vyska, rychlost, sila_dashe):
        self.x = y
        self.y = y
        self.sirka = sirka
        self.vyska = vyska
        self.rychlost = rychlost
        self.sila_dashe = sila_dashe
        self.jde_vpravo = False
        self.jde_vlevo = False
        self.jde_nahoru = False
        self.jde_dolu = False
        self.stoji = True
        self.dashuje = False
        self.pocet_kroku = 0
        self.snimek_dashe = 0 

    def animace_hrace(self, okno):
        if self.pocet_kroku + 1 >= 18:
            self.pocet_kroku = 0
        
        if not self.stoji:
            if self.jde_vlevo:  
                okno.blit(animaceVlevo[hrac.pocet_kroku//3], (round(hrac.x),round(hrac.y)))
                self.pocet_kroku += 1                          
            elif self.jde_vpravo:
                okno.blit(animaceVpravo[hrac.pocet_kroku//3], (round(hrac.x),round(hrac.y)))
                self.pocet_kroku += 1
            elif hrac.jde_nahoru:
                okno.blit(animaceNahoru[hrac.pocet_kroku//3], (round(hrac.x),round(hrac.y)))
                self.pocet_kroku += 1
            else:
                okno.blit(animaceDolu[hrac.pocet_kroku//3], (round(hrac.x),round(hrac.y)))
                self.pocet_kroku += 1
        else:
            okno.blit(animaceStoji[hrac.pocet_kroku//3], (round(hrac.x),round(hrac.y)))
            self.pocet_kroku += 1

    def animace_dashe(self, okno):
        x = self.x + self.sirka
        y = self.y + self.vyska * 0.25
        if self.snimek_dashe + 1 >= 7:
            self.snimek_dashe = 0
            
        if self.dashuje:
            self.snimek_dashe += 0.25
            okno.blit(animaceDash[int(self.snimek_dashe)], (round(x),round(y)))
 
    def pohyb_hrace(self):
        if (klavesa[py.K_a] or klavesa[py.K_LEFT]) and self.x > self.rychlost:
            self.jde_vlevo = True
            self.jde_vpravo = False
            self.jde_nahoru = False
            self.jde_dolu = False
            self.stoji = False
            self.x -= self.rychlost
            if (klavesa[py.K_e]) and self.x > self.sila_dashe:
                self.dashuje = True
                self.x -= self.sila_dashe
            if (klavesa[py.K_w] or klavesa[py.K_UP]) and self.y > self.rychlost:
                hrac.y -= self.rychlost
            if (klavesa[py.K_s] or klavesa[py.K_DOWN]) and self.y > self.rychlost:
                hrac.y += self.rychlost
        elif (klavesa[py.K_d] or klavesa[py.K_RIGHT]) and self.x < sirka_okna - self.sirka - self.rychlost:
            self.jde_vlevo = False
            self.jde_vpravo = True
            self.jde_nahoru = False
            self.jde_dolu = False
            self.stoji = False
            self.x += self.rychlost
            if (klavesa[py.K_e]) and self.x < sirka_okna - self.sila_dashe - self.sirka:
                self.dashuje = True
                self.x += self.sila_dashe
            if (klavesa[py.K_w] or klavesa[py.K_UP]) and self.y > self.rychlost:
                hrac.y -= self.rychlost
            if (klavesa[py.K_s] or klavesa[py.K_DOWN]) and self.y > self.rychlost:
                hrac.y += self.rychlost
        elif (klavesa[py.K_w] or klavesa[py.K_UP]) and self.y > self.rychlost:
            self.jde_vlevo = False
            self.jde_vpravo = False
            self.jde_nahoru = True
            self.jde_dolu = False
            self.stoji = False
            self.y -= hrac.rychlost
            if (klavesa[py.K_e]) and self.y > self.sila_dashe:
                self.dashuje = True
                self.y -= self.sila_dashe           
        elif (klavesa[py.K_s] or klavesa[py.K_DOWN]) and self.y < vyska_okna - self.vyska - self.rychlost:
            self.jde_vlevo = False
            self.jde_vpravo = False
            self.jde_nahoru = False
            self.jde_dolu = True
            self.stoji = False
            self.y += self.rychlost
            if (klavesa[py.K_e]) and self.y < vyska_okna - self.sila_dashe - self.sirka:
                self.dashuje = True
                self.y += self.sila_dashe
        else:
            self.stoji = True
            self.pocet_kroku = 0
            self.dashuje = False
            self.snimek_dashe = 0

  
def vytvor_level():
    for objekt in range(200):
        x = random.randint(0, sirka_okna)
        y = random.randint(0, vyska_okna)
        trava = random.choice(travy)
        okno.blit(trava, (x,y))
        x = random.randint(0, sirka_okna)
        y = random.randint(0, vyska_okna)
        kytka = random.choice(kytky)
        okno.blit(kytka, (x,y))
        
def aktulizace_okna():
    okno.blit(pozadi, (0,0))
    hrac.animace_hrace(okno)
    hrac.animace_dashe(okno)
    vytvor_level()
    py.display.update()
    
hrac = Hrac(10, 458, 40, 40, 3, 20)


tik = py.time.Clock()


while bezi_program:
    tik.tick(60)

    for event in py.event.get():
        if event.type == py.QUIT:
            bezi_program = False

    klavesa = py.key.get_pressed()

    hrac.pohyb_hrace()
        
    #if hrac.x < enemy.x + enemy.sirka and hrac.x + hrac.sirka > enemy.x and hrac.y < enemy.y + enemy.vyska and hrac.y + hrac.vyska > enemy.y:
        #print("Kolize detekována")

    aktulizace_okna()
            
py.quit()
```

Comment: I suppose You could detect somehow that a level is finished. so then in the main loop just put in an `if statement` that checks for that like so `if level_finished:` and the next line could be `genereate_new_level()`

Answer (score -1):

Ok i managed to do it. I used Pillow to paste all the generated images to my background and then keep displaying that one background.